# Question about particle にも

Tags: grammar

I cannot grasp what  にも means between 身のほど知らず and 敵対する愚 in the following sentence, maybe something like "foolishness of taking up arms not knowing their place" ?

As far as I can understand the sentence:
"Let them taste true fear. Make them remember the foolishness of (身のほど知らずにも) taking up arms against our nation and our people, and then allow them to savor their bitter victory!"

> 奴らには恐怖を与えろ。この国に、我々に、身のほど知らず**にも**敵対する愚を思い知らせ、後に矮小な勝利をくれてやれ。

Thank you!

Comment: It's the same にも as in 愚かにも(≒愚かなことに; foolishly; foolish enough to...), 幸いにも(≒幸いなことに; fortunately), 不幸/不運にも(≒不幸/不運なことに; unfortunately) etc... So I think 身の程知らずにも is like 身の程知らずなことに...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the emphatic も that is used frequently in Japanese.  It emphasizes the word or phrase that immediately precededs it.  In this case it is 身のほど知らずに that is being emphasized.

身のほど知らずにも = "not having the slightest idea who they are (or 'what position they are in')"

Comment: Thank you very much for help. If I'm understanding correctly from your explanation, も here used only for emphasis, and it is not the same にも as in 愚かにも(≒愚かなことに; foolishly; foolish enough to...), 幸いにも(≒幸いなことに; fortunately), 不幸/不運にも(≒不幸/不運なことに; unfortunately) etc..., is this right ?